# How to set up hibernate on mate 18.04

Tags: grub, hibernate

```
cat /proc/swaps

Filename Type Size Used Priority
/swapfile file 2097148 0 -2

cat /etc/default/grub | grep resume

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/swapfile"
```

it does not recover the previous workspace after hibernation, but it is not a clean restart as the network does not work. checking for a sleep process does not find any.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered it is not possible to use a swapfile to hibernate. There is a workaround by using uswsusp and the solution is here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file

I will just create a swap partition and hibernate the usual way.